# how to make background css URL in codeigniter?

Tags: php, html, css, codeigniter

I'm trying to display some images using the background url in CSS but is not working. I put this code in one of my CSS selector

```
        background:url(../assets/images/teksture2.png);
```

and view code

```
        <!doctype html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta content-type: "text/css" charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Aplikasi Inventori Barang</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url("assets/css/layout.css");?>">

    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="header">
            <div class="image"><img src="<?php echo base_url("assets/images/logo.png");?>" alt="logo"></div>
        </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

and in controller file is

```
    <?php

    /**
    * 
    */
    class Home extends CI_Controller
    {

        function __construct()
        {
            parent::__construct();
        }

        function index()
        {
            $this->load->helper('url');
            $this->load->view('index');
        }
    }

?>
```

can you help me solve this problem?

Comment: Solve *what* problem? Please provide some details about **exactly** what is *"not working"*. Do you have any error messages (including in your browser's developer console)?

Comment: where does the css file reside?

Answer (score 1):

Hope css and images folders exist inside the asset folder. Then in your `css` file, you have to use below code.

```
 background:url(../images/teksture2.png);
```

Comment: Downvoter care to comment? This looks about right to me

Comment: i always use code like that in css file but background is not display

Comment: did you check path of file?

Comment: if my solution is helpful, then accept it. It will helpful others too to find better solution.